# Use notFound() in dynamic routes at root in Next.js

Tags: next.js

My Next.js 14 app has this router configuration:

```
app
 |--[slug]
 |    |--page.tsx
 |--layout.tsx
 |--not-found.tsx
 |--page.tsx
```

As you can see, I want to have a dynamic route at root: domain.com/`slug`.

Here is the `[slug]/page.tsx`:

```js
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation';
import { getArticleBySlug } from '@/lib/api';

export default function Article({ params }: IParams) {
  const article = getArticleBySlug(params.slug);

  if (!article) notFound();

  return <></>;
}
```

However, when I tried to use `notFound()` I got an error `notFound() is not allowed to use in root layout`.

This is necessary when the article does not exist. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You can try creating a minimal repro and see if the error is triggered somewhere else. I just created a project from scratch with your layout, and I do not see an error you are describing. Hope this helps.

Comment: Error indicates you have a notFound in `layout.tsx`? Don't you?

Comment: @IgorDanchenko great idea, I built and ran the app, surprisingly the problem didn’t appear on production.

Comment: @grekier the error said that but I didn’t include it in `layout.tsx`.

Comment: After debugging, this error happens when returning `<></>` in `not-found.tsx`. I left it empty because this is in early dev stage.